# Send command-line arguments to MonkeyRunner script

Tags: android, testing, functional-testing, monkeyrunner

I am starting to explore writing MonkeyRunner scripts as part of my test suite. I am testing two apps: a free version and a paid version. I would like to write a single test script which I can run against either of these two apps. Is it possible to send command-line arguments to my MonkeyRunner script? For example, I imagine providing the Android package name in this way. Or perhaps is there another solution to my problem? I'm certainly open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. `sys.argv` contains the command line options and arguments you may have passed to the script.
In this regard there's no difference with other python interpreters.
The only thing you should avoid is to use command line options `-u`, `-s`, `-p`, `-v` and `-plugin` as they are used by `monkeyrunner` itself, albeit some of them not documented.

Comment: I'm a noob to Python in general, so to clarify, I can run `monkeyrunner test.py com.example` and `"com.example"` is one of the elements of `sys.argv`, right?

Comment: Got it! I can definitely figure out the details from here.